# Multiple domains, one rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a rails 5 application that I would like to be able to be accessed by different URLS. For example, the following two URLS would be powered by the same app;

- example.com.au
- example.co.nz

Let's say on the homepage of each I wanted to display a list of links to that countries main cities. Each main city will also have it's own page;

- example.com.au/sydney
- example.co.nz/auckland

They would share the same database.

This seems like it would be a common problem but I've been unable to find a straightforward answer.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to display different content based on the current domain?

Answer (score 1):

I'd "register" the URLs in a hash somewhere in your app:

```
{
  "example.com.au" => "AU",
  "example.co.nz" => "NZ",
}
```

Then you can add a method in your controller that looks something like this, to get the country:

```
def current_country
  domain_name = extract_domain_name(request.original_url)
  Settings.domain_country_map[domain_name]
end
```

If you're using a database to save the countries that `have_many` cities, you'd do a find in that method. And, for the home page, you can show `current_country.cities.popular.limit(5)` or something like that.

I also assume you wouldn't want `example.co.nz/sydney` to work. In that case, make sure that you scope it to the country: when the `/city_name` url is hit, you do a `current_country.cities.find_by(slug: params[:city_slug])`.

To make the route `/city_slug` work, you'd need something like this in your routes file:

get '/:city_slug', to: 'cities#show'

Answer (score -1):

There are probably better ways of doing it, but if you call request.url, rails will return the current address. For example we could make the following in our application controller:

```
expose(:sydney?)
expose(:auckland?)

def sydney?
  request.url.include?('sydney')
end

def auckland?
  request.url.include?('auckland')
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% if sydney? %>
  <%= Do some stuff %>
<% elsif auckland? %>
  <%= Do some other stuff %>
<% else %>
  <%= Do stuff for no city %>
<% end %>
```

Remember to expose both methods in your controller or you can't access them from your view.

Comment: You should mention that the `expose` method comes from the [`decent_exposure`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/259-decent-exposure) gem.

Comment: Good point! Part of my default setup I forget I even include it any more